# How to make the scrollcontroller of a TextField follow the current position of the cursor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to create a custom keyboard so that my application has its own style. I got the device keyboard not showing up but now I am faced with the problem that when I type and the cursor leaves the image the TextField does not follow the cursor automatically like when typing with the device keyboard. Does anyone have any idea how I can make the scroll move with the cursor and if the cursor is already being seen then it does not move?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DM9eS6_JOnm_RFPBaQNWKAUBrw8urjjA/view?usp=sharing) I leave a video that shows what I say so that you can get a better idea, at first I simply give a text that is wrapped with a GestureDetector so that the onTap function adds the text I want to my textController.text and it looks As the scroll does not move with the cursor but later I hit the device keyboard again and it does move with it, which is the behavior I want. I had to put it in a drive link since stackoverflow does not allow to put videos here.

I also leave my TextField code so that you can see it and tell me if there are any errors and that is why it does not work as I want.

```
class ValueInput extends StatefulWidget {
  const ValueInput({
    Key? key,
    required this.valueText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String valueText;

  @override
  State<ValueInput> createState() => _ValueInputState();
}

class _ValueInputState extends State<ValueInput> {
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController(text: '0');
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  FocusNode nodo = FocusNode();
  int count = 0;

  void _insertText(
    TextEditingController controller,
    FocusNode node,
    String myText,
  ) async {
    Future<bool> focused() async {
      return node.hasFocus;
    }

    if (!node.hasFocus) {
      node.requestFocus();
    }
    await focused() == true;
    final text = controller.text;
    final textSelection = controller.selection;
    final newText = text.replaceRange(
      textSelection.start,
      textSelection.end,
      myText,
    );
    final myTextLength = myText.length;
    controller.text = newText;
    controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: textSelection.start + myTextLength));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Brightness brightness =
        WidgetsBinding.instance!.platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
    final prefs = PreferenciasUsuario();
    final border = OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        width: 2.0,
        style: BorderStyle.solid,
        color: Tema.color3,
      ),
    );

    return Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            count++;
            _insertText(textController, nodo, count.toString());
          },
          child: Text(
            'Valor ${widget.valueText}',
            style: MyTextStyles().defaultStyle.copyWith(color: Tema.blanco),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 1.h(context)),
        SizedBox(
          height: 6.h(context),
          width: 25.w(context),
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: nodo,
            controller: textController,
            scrollController: scrollController,
            // readOnly: true,
            // showCursor: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            keyboardAppearance: (prefs.tema == 2)
                ? Brightness.light
                : (prefs.tema == 3)
                    ? Brightness.dark
                    : (brightness == Brightness.dark)
                        ? Brightness.dark
                        : Brightness.light,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: MyTextStyles()
                .defaultStyle
                .copyWith(color: Tema.negro, fontSize: 14.sp(context)),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              enabledBorder: border,
              focusedBorder: border,
              disabledBorder: border,
              errorBorder: border,
              focusedErrorBorder: border,
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Tema.blanco,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me, it is the only thing I lack to be able to have my application 100% as I want.

Answer (score -1):

I think the `scrollController` params is your solution.
Depending on how you want to listen to text changes in your editor, you can reuse code like this:

```
String text = '';
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

scrollToCursor(String textFieldValue) {
    final isLonger = textFieldValue.length > text.length;
    text = textFieldValue;
    if (isLonger) _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
}
// use _scrollController.position.viewportDimension if text field is one line
```

And inside the `build` method :

```
TextField(
            scrollController: _scrollController,
            //controller: _controller,  // if needed
            maxLines: null,
            onChanged: (value) {
                scrollToCursor(value);
            }
)
```

Of course, don't forget to `dispose()` your `scrollController` like this :

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't use the onChanged function because it's a custom keyboard so I don't know if it's because of that but it works only at the beginning there comes a time when it stops working. I already tried something also with ScrollController, but the same thing happened to me, that's why I decided to ask to see if someone knew how to do it. Also thanks Matt.